# org.hibernate.TransientObjectException, how modify method to set instance to persistence state

Tags: hibernate

i need modify a method from one of my controller classes to get rid a hibernate exception about null indentifier and make a update on DAO class, look like this:

```
public void updateDealerName(String name){    

      DealerListView dealer = new DealerListView();

  if(dealer.getDealerId() == getSelectedDealerId()) {

    DealerData dealDat = new DealerData();
    dealDat.setName(name);
    BeanFactory.getHotelDAOService(DealerData.class).update(dealDat); }
```

selectedDealerId or his getter getSelectedDealerId() - there is stored a dealer ID from dealer list

DealerData = is a DAO

DealerListView - is used in projection of properties for create a detachedcriteria knows from hibernate

How can be modified this method so a null indentifier exception are disapeared and make transient instance "dealDat" make persist, is need somehow asign a Selected dealer ID to a instance? Can somebody post advice here? If yes i'll be very thankful.

Comment: Have you tried [Session.saveOrUpate](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadoc/org/hibernate/Session.html#saveOrUpdate(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object))

Comment: You should show us the complete stack trace of the exception, and the code which causes this exception (and which is probably in the DAO).